# If I create a connection pooling in websphere Application server do I need to change anything in Java code?

Tags: connection-pooling, websphere-8

I am using WAS and DB2 and my Application is coded in Java.
If I create a connection pooling in websphere Application server, then do I need to change anything in Java code? or Websphere will handle all connection pooling concept?

Answer (score 5):

To take advantage of connection pooling provided by WebSphere Application Server, you need to obtain connections from data source.  First configure the data source and assign a jndiName to it.

Then you can use resource injection to define a resource reference for it and inject into a Java EE component, for example,

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/ds1", name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/ds1ref")
DataSource ds1;
```

or look it up in JNDI, for example,

```
    DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ds1ref");
```

Always make sure to close connections that obtain from the data source when you are done with them so they can go back to the pool,

```
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        con.close();
    }
```

If your application needs to access any JDBC vendor APIs (not part of the JDBC specification), use the JDBC wrapper pattern (unwrap method).  For example,

```
OracleConnection oraCon = con.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Other than that, usage of connection pooling should be pretty much transparent.